# MVC add data to database show with JSON in page

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc-3

I designed a web site with MVC 3. I want to add a row in database and show in page. I used from JsonResult. Everything is ok but when show in view, all cells show undefined. After refreshing page get data from database and solve problem, but with JSON I have problem.

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult ContactIns(ContactUs Info)
{
    try
    {
        Dbcon.ContactUsS.Add(Info);
        Dbcon.SaveChanges();            
    }
    catch
    {

    }

    var formattedData = Dbcon.ContactUsS.Where(m => m.idn == Info.idn).Select(
                              m => new
                              {
                                  nam = m.nam,
                                  EmailAdd = m.EmailAdd,
                                  Tel = m.Tel
                              });

    return Json(formattedData);
}
```

and in view like this:

```
    function JsonAdd_OnComplete(data) {
        alert(data);
        var target = $('#InsRec');
        target.append('<tr><td>' + data.nam + '</td><td>'
        + data.EmailAdd + '</td>+<td>' + data.Tel + '</td><td><a href="http://www.toseeads.com">حذف</a></td></tr>');
        //close Dialog 
         $(".dialog").dialog("close");
}
```

please help me thanks a lot

Comment: try `data.emailAdd` and `data.tel` instead of  `data.EmailAdd` or `data.Tel`. and while using objects use `console.log` instead of `alert`

Comment: Need to have your JS scripts. How do you call you C# method from JS?